# How can I implement a RESTful API for a React app?

Tags: reactjs, json, express, rest

I'm new to both React and microservices. I'm building a UI application using React, it will connect to a database in the future but the app itself is just the frontend of the system. To deploy it on my cloud provider, it requires that the app has a health check endpoint so that when the cloud provider pings /healthcheck the app answers with a JSON file containing an HTTP status code and a message to test for readiness and availability. I'm not sure how to do this.

I looked online for how to implement a REST API in React but they all talk about consuming from React and not serving from it. What can I do? Is it possible to install Express within my React app? I understand that typically an Express backend and a React frontend live separately, so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

React itself is just a frontend library and therefore doesn't contain the ability to run a server in the way you are looking for.

Once you're app is finished, you'll end up building the React app anyway and will need a separate server (or a static site hosting service like GitHub Pages) to actually serve the compiled website.

An Express.js server is one way to do it. As I say, you'll need a server to serve the website anyway, so your Express.js server could also expose this endpoint as you desire.

If you want to include the API as a part of the React project, the closest you will get is to migrate to Next.js, which has a feature called API Routes, which allows for behaviour like you are looking for.

Look into both, and see which works best for you:

- Express.js - https://expressjs.com/
- Next.js API Routes - https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes